# Share details of post on a wall

Tags: facebook-graph-api, share

I am interested in tracking the user IDs of those who are sharing the wall posts on my fanpage. Does the graph api now support returning the user IDs of the user who have shared the wall post on their wall like I can see who all commented & liked the post?

Any possible workarounds?

Comment: Any updates? I'm interested in this too.

Comment: I'm trying to learn how to do this also and without any success. It seems this is imposible

Comment: Update: You can do it via "graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/sharedposts" connection.

Comment: Thanks! If you can post that as an answer, I will accept.

Answer (score -1):

yes it's possible you can do through facebook graph api.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

get all post with comments + comment user id + liked user id.

these data managed by your own database.

Comment: read the ques again, I am taking about shares, and not likes or comments